Differential equation of perpendicular lines
Determine the differential equation of all straight lines who are at a unit distance from the origin.
If we assume the line to be of the form $ax+by+c=0$,then unit distance condition implies $|c|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. So,our line is finally of the form $ax+by\pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Now since there are $2$ arbitrary constants,we need to differentiate twice.
Differentiating once gives us $a+by'=0$. Differentiating again gives us $by''=0$ or $y''=0$ which obviously isn't the actual solution since $y''=0$ is basically the differential equation of all lines in the plane.
However assuming the line to be of the form $y=mx+c$ gives us our required result since it boils down to $1$ arbitrary constants. Now,my question is why did the first approach give us wrong answer whereas it shouldn't?

As you present it, no need to go to the second derivative to have a contradiction : already for the first derivative $a+by'=0 \iff y'=-a/b$ whose solutions are already all the lines of the plane. Advice : turn to a one-parameter parametrisation $(L_{\theta,x,y}) \ : \ \ \sin \theta x - \cos \theta y +1=0$. In fact the differentiation must be made with respect to all the "characters", $x,y,a,b$ or, much simpler $x,y,\theta$.

The easiest way to see why there's only one degree of freedom is probably to notice that it's enough to choose the point on the unit circle that the line passes through.
